# sort_index() function in Armadillo library gives wrong result

Tags: c++, armadillo

I am trying to use the `sort_index()` function in the Armadillo C++ library [(link here)](http://arma.sourceforge.net/docs.html#sort_index).

Here is my code:

```
#include <armadillo>
#include <iostream>
using namespace arma;
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    vec test = {2, 5, 1};
    test.print();
    sort_index(test).print();
    cout<<"===\n";
    sort_index(test, "descend").print();

    return 0;
}
```

And the result is:

```
2.0000
5.0000
1.0000
    2
    0
    1
===
    1
    0
    2
```

I think the descend order is correct but the ascend order is wrong. It seems just like a reflect version of descend order. Is this a bug? If two result are both correct, what does `sort_index()` actually do?

Comment: Does it not make sense that sorted in descending order is the exact opposite of sorted in ascending order? If you read the elements at indices 2, 0, and 1, you get the elements sorted in ascending order. If you read the elements at indices 1, 0, and 2, you get the elements in descending order. Seems fine to me.

Comment: I think ascending order must be (2-1),(2-0),(2-2) = 1,2,0

Comment: I don't know how you arrived at that conclusion, you seem to be very confused (please don't take that personally). I think you need to discuss this with someone, the comments section is not ideal for this. If you want to reverse the order of the elements displayed, you simply reverse the order you access the elements: i.e. reverse the list of indices.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`sort_index(test, "descend").print();`

Will print in descending order (highest first).

`sort_index(test, "ascend").print();`

Prints in ascending order (smallest first, a reflection of descending order) This is used by default when the function is called.

What seems to be wrong with that? Check out the documentation for `sort_index()` [here](http://arma.sourceforge.net/docs.html#sort_index).

Comment: Well, just those lines won't print anything. This answer doesn't really help anyone, other than illustrating that the question is not clear.

Comment: @BoBTFish Updated answer.

Comment: The result of sort_index(test, "ascend").print(); is 2,0,1. What it really mean?

Comment: @AArtint It is printing the numbers out in a way so that when it is done it leaves a list in ascending order.

Comment: Ah. Now I understand. I misunderstand the document. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

The result is correct. The function `sort_index` works as same as Python's `numpy.argsort`. It yields the indices of the original list to make a sorted list.

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> x = np.array([2, 5, 1])
>>> idx = np.argsort(x); print(idx)
[2 0 1]
>>> x_sorted = x[idx]; print(x_sorted)
[1 2 5]
```